# Web Service transfer (XML) examples

Tags: xml, web-services, rest

I'm doing a research about WS-Transfer through XML. I was looking for different XML implementations that are used for WS-Transfer but i can't find that much info about it. Is there an overview of XML templates that are used by web services? This could be OWL-S, DAML+OIL, etc.

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow. It will be much easier for us to help you with your question if you would describe [what you have already tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: @LutzHorn You mean where I already looked for this information? I looked through of course Google and article libraries like IEEExplore and Ovip SP

Comment: And what was the result of this research? Please describe in your question what you have tried, why, what doesn't work, what you want the result to be, ...

Comment: @LutzHorn I'm not sure what you mean... What I tried was to search for examples of XML-implementations that are used for WS-Transfer. The result was that I could not find them. What i want the result to be is to obtain examples of XML-implementations that are used for WS-Transfer. I hope this clears it out a bit.